# what's the default color scheme of pantheon terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal, configuration, colors, color-management

The Color Scheme in elementary is super but I didn't know the name of it.

I want to integrate it on all my software to have a nice and clean experience :)

Comment: This should be asked in the [elementaryos.se] site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a quick look in the dconf settings for Pantheon Terminal (org.pantheon.terminal.settings):

The background color appears to be #252e32 with opacity 95%, the cursor color appears to be #839496, and the the foreground color appears to be #94a3a5.

For future reference, `dconf-editor` is a useful package to have.